# What to use as a substitute for NumberUtils->Digit()

Tags: java

`org.apache.commons.lang.NumberUtils` is deprecated and I have not found what to use instead of this class in same jar `commons-lang-2.6.jar`

Updated:
I could not realize the description,

```
Deprecated. Moved to org.apache.commons.lang.math. Class will be removed in Commons Lang 3.0.
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/NumberUtils.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like the [javadoc of NumberUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/NumberUtils.html) says, the class is moved to the [math subpackage](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html)

Answer (score 6):

It is now :

[org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html)

moved to the `math` sub package.